# Storing facebook session data

Tags: php, facebook

I am using the Facebook PHP SDK and am storing the session when a user logs in...

```
if ($session = $facebook->getSession()) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE fb_session SET app_session = '" . addslashes(serialize($session)) . "' WHERE user_id = " . $uid);
}
```

I have a cron script running that uses the facebook API as the user via:

```
$facebook->setSession(unserialize($row['app_session']), false);
```

To set the script to the right user.

The problem is when a user logs out of facebook, the session is no longer valid and requires them to login again. I have a cron script so this screws it up as there is no user interaction.

Am I meant to be storing something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do?

If you just want to publish on behalf of the user then just ask for the `publish_stream` permission and store the user id in your DB.
After that you can publish without "getting a session" (i.e. without `$facebook->setSession(...)`).

And if you want to do other tasks, then aquire the `offline_access` permission and *only* store the `access_token` along with the user id in your DB, and perform your tasks also without `setSession`

Comment: aside from a security issue would using setSession over sending the access token be any different i.e. would the session expire and access token have no timeout?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but as I said...if you only need to "publish" then you only need `publish_stream` and user id, so valid session or access token. Now for other things you need `offline_access` **AND** to store `access_token` + USER_ID, the access token retrieved will not timeout and **NO NEED** to check set the session whether it's expired or not!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to request the `offline_access` permission when your users connect with your application, which gives you permanent instead of temporary access tokens.